# ColdFusion 9 I/O Exception: Connection reset

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfhttp, connection-reset

I need help. Working with ColdFusion 9 and I'm trying to do a CFHTTP POST to a 3rd party payment gateway. I keep running into 'Connection Failure' messages and it tell me 'I/O Exception: Connection reset'. Not 'peer not authenticated'. Is this still a cert issue?

Another issue with this is that not all calls will fail. Maybe 1 in 300. I'm at a total loss. I don't even know what info to provide. Let me know how to help with more information.

I've looked at many resources like this similar [Adobe question](https://forums.adobe.com/message/8464384#8464384). It doesn't seem to be answered either. I've added the binary thing to my process and still getting errors. [image: Error I'm getting]

Thanks guys. I'm hoping to get this solved soon.

Comment: try adding the cert file of the site to the keystore.

Comment: Are you connecting to a secure site over HTTPS? If so, then you must have the certificate installed into the Java keystore that your ColdFusion server is using (if it is not already).

Comment: Yes I am but wouldn't that then make every call fail? If the cert wasn't installed right, then it would happen every time right?

Comment: So, I went ahead and reinstalled the cert again, restarted the service and now so far it's working... So hopefully...?